# Launching same toast from multiple buttons in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I want to build a website using Bootstrap and basically I have some divs (containing details about events) that come from a database, shown on the website using HTML and JS. The structure of the divs is the same for all the events, and at the bottom of the div I have a Delete button, thus I have multiple buttons calling the same toast. When pressing the Delete button, a toast should appear where I should confirm my deletion. The problem is that it gives me the error: **Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.toast.** How can I solve this error?

I have done this:

```
`<div class="toast" id="deleteBooking" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="toast-body">
        Do you really want to delete this event?
        <div class="mt-2 pt-2 border-top">
            <button type="button" class="deleteButton" onclick="deleteEvent()">Delete event</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="toast">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div> <button type="button" class="delete-event" id = "delete-event" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteBooking">Delete event</button>`;
</div>

<script>
    const deleteEventButton = document.getElementById("delete-event");
    const toastDeleteEvent = new bootstrap.Toast(document.querySelector('#deleteBooking'));
 deleteEventButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        toastDeleteEvent.show();
    });
</script>`
```